# Save full url for many sites on Xhgui DB

Tags: php, profiling, profiler, xhprof

I have **installed and running** [XhGUI](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui)+XhProf on Nginx + Php-fpm. Right now I am profiling many sites but when I check site1.local/ or site2.local/, XhGUI save all this under the same meta-url "/"

How Can I save the full url for every site in the XhGUI MongoDB?

Thanks.

Comment: Please doesn't post installation steps described here: https://github.com/perftools/xhgui. This is not a basic installation issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the hostname piece of the uri when you tell `xhgui` to save it.

If you followed the installation steps and used the provided `header.php` then the area you are looking to customize is between [lines 122-128](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui/blob/master/external/header.php#L122-L128).